# Java <Streams> How to sort the list of my objects, based on the count of the components of the List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 classes in Java. One is a Car class that consists of 5 variables. Among them I have a List equipment variable. Another class contains the list of the Car class objects: List carlist.

My task is: I have to sort the list of car object, using Streams in Java based on the amount of the equipment items that the given car have.

How do I do that? I tried to build a separate method to count the items on the list of the object - but then within the Comparator I can't place an Object as an argument of this method.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
private int countEquipmentItems (Car s){
    if (s == null){
        return 0;
    }
    int countEquipment = 0;
    List<String> a = s.getEquipment();
    for (int i = 0; i <a.size() ; i++) {
        countEquipment ++;
    }
    return countEquipment;
}
```

And I have tried to use this method within the Stream:

```
public void sortbyEquipment (List<Car> carList){
    carList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(countEquipmentItems(Car s)));
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: Do you have to use streams? It would make more sense to sort the list in place.

Comment: Didn’t it occur to yourself that `for (int i = 0; i <a.size() ; i++) { countEquipment ++; }` is a verbose way to say `countEquipment += a.size();`?

Comment: Yes, I have to use streams - that's the part of the excercise. As for the second comment - yeah, now that you pointed that out it's obvious. Sorry - rookie mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need that `countEquipmentItems` method to count the amount of equipment. Just use `car.getEquipment().size()`:

```
public void sortbyEquipment (List<Car> carList){
    carList.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(car -> car.getEquipment().size()))
           ...
}
```

Of course, you can pass that `Comparator` directly to `Collections.sort()`, which will sort the list without having to create a `Stream`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `countEquipmentItems` method is redundant and completely unnecessary.

Another solution to what Eran has provided would be to call the default `sort` method that is available for the `List<T>` type.

```
carList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(car -> car.getEquipment().size()));
```

or if you want the sorted items to be in a new collection then you can do:

```
List<Car> clonedList = new ArrayList<>(carList); // clone the carList
clonedList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(car -> car.getEquipment().size()));
```